# Tensorboard fails to Launch

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3, tensorflow2.x

Tensorboard fails to launch. I get the following error messages. Can somebody guide. I have reinstalled conda and Tensorflow multiple times. I also looked online for similar issues, have not found anything.
Python 3.7.4 and Tensforflow version 2.1

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard-script.py", line 9, in 
sys.exit(run_main())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 65, in run_main
default.get_plugins() + default.get_dynamic_plugins(),
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 125, in get_dynamic_plugins
"tensorboard_plugins"
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 124, in 
for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 2442, in load
self.require(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 2465, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 786, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'typing-extensions>=3.7.4; python_version < "3.8"' distribution was not found and is required by yarl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install typing-extensions.